# Link javascript web application to java

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, rhino, nashorn

I'm trying to get java and javascript to talk to each other. Ideally, I would want them to share objects, but it would be enough that a java-application calls a javascript function. I've tried Rhino but struggle a bit, because it doesn't seem able to call functions in a running js-engine (maybe it can I just couldn't figure out how?). Any tips on how to make this link happen? Performance is an issue but not extremely critical.

Basically; I have a web application that uses javascript to update the content of the page dynamically. The content of the page is created through java-code, so I need a way for the java-code to tell the javascript when something changes and what changes.

Thanks

LiveConnect seems to do the trick, but applet would be a security-leak. Would Nashorn in Java8 do the same as Rhino or will it be able to keep a running JVM and listen to calls?

Comment: You're going to need to explain what you're after in more detail.

Comment: Rhino (and the whole javax.script package) allow you to invoke Javascript from within Java, not the other way around.   Amongst other things you can pass the javascript java objects, the javascript can access Java classes and you can get your javascript to implement Java interfaces.  It creates its own javascript engine to execute the code. I don't see how it could ever work with a random external one in the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to make the Java back end and JavaScript talk directly to each other the way you imply you want to do. The only way to make them communicate is through AJAX or WebSockets.

Comment: Seems like Nashorn does the trick though, I can access my Java-objects from JS and vice versa. However, nashorn doesn't have functionality for window etc..

Comment: To use libs etc from e.g. Node.js and similar, it turns out Rhino/Nashorn doesn't cut it. I ended up using WebSockets.